# Printing a black box with escpos using javascript qz-tray

Tags: javascript, escpos, qz-tray

As the title says, i would like to know how to print black boxes on a thermal printer, since using these characters didn't work.

```
String.fromCharCode(2588)
String.fromCharCode(2580)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_charcode_en/index.php?content_id=10) CharCode reference on epson website